# Plotting occurrences of patches against increasing distance from turtle

Tags: plot, netlogo

I have searched through existing questions but could not find an answer to this yet.

I have a model simulating spatial pattern across a landscape and would like to  plot, on Netlogo, the occurrences of patches with specified colors on y-axis against increasing distance from a specific turtle. I have looked through the models library but most of the plots were against time, which is not relevant in my case since I am not simulating temporal changes.

So far, from existing models, the idea I've got is I should have this line

```
count patches with [pcolor = red]
```

But how do I setup the plot in a way to get it to count against increasing distance instead of the usual time steps? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you add a plot named "plot 1".  Then you could histogram the distances.  E.g.,

```
to illustrate
  ca
  ask patches [set pcolor one-of [red white blue]]
  crt 1
  ask turtle 0 [
    set-current-plot "plot 1"
    set-plot-pen-mode 1
    histogram [distance myself] of patches with [pcolor = red]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hey Alan, thanks for your answer! I got your method to work, but is there a way, instead of plotting histograms I could plot line graphs instead? Since I would like to plot the lines of occurrences for multiple pcolors on one graph. Thanks again! :)

Comment: ah sorry I figured out it was the plot-pen-mode thanks!

Comment: But isn't it possible now to code inside the graph itself, instead of the main code? Or is that only applicable to over time graphs? Thanks!

Comment: @lyh198 You can definitely put the code in the graph, as usual.
Separately: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work